# JmsTemplate with RECEIVE_TIMEOUT_NO_WAIT doesn't retrieve messages from JMS queue

Tags: spring, jms, spring-jms, jmstemplate

Given I have ActiveMQ queue where many messages are already present.

When I set receive timeout on `JmsTemplate` to `RECEIVE_TIMEOUT_NO_WAIT` which is equal to `-1`:

```
jmsTemplate.setReceiveTimeout(JmsTemplate.RECEIVE_TIMEOUT_NO_WAIT);
```

and try to receive one of those messages:

```
Message msg = jmsTemplate.receive(queueName);
```

then `msg` is `null`, but it should not be according JavaDoc:

```
/**
 * Timeout value indicating that a receive operation should
 * check if a message is immediately available without blocking.
 */
public static final long RECEIVE_TIMEOUT_NO_WAIT = -1;
```

Why is that?

When I do:

```
jmsTemplate.setReceiveTimeout(1000);
```

then messages are retrieved.

Comment: I suspect subsequent no wait calls will work (after the first one with wait). I just looked at the `ActiveMQMessageConsumer.receiveNoWait()` method and he sends a pull request but, of course, that request is not satisfied immediately so there are no messages yet. Eventually those messages will arrive and the no wait option should work.

Comment: It seems weird.. what's the advantage of re-configuring `JmsTemplate` from some timeout to `RECEIVE_TIMEOUT_NO_WAIT`.. I can just keep using original timeout.. I don't see any use case for it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has absolutely nothing at all to do with the `JmsTemplate` since it simply delegates to the underlying JMS `Consumer` object:

```
protected Message receiveFromConsumer(MessageConsumer consumer, long timeout) throws JMSException {
    if (timeout > 0) {
        return consumer.receive(timeout);
    }
    else if (timeout < 0) {
        return consumer.receiveNoWait();
    }
    else {
        return consumer.receive();
    }
}
```

I would say it is working exactly as the JMS designers intended:

```
/** Receives the next message if one is immediately available.
  *
  * @return the next message produced for this message consumer, or 
  * null if one is not available
  *  
  * @exception JMSException if the JMS provider fails to receive the next
  *                         message due to some internal error.
  */ 

Message receiveNoWait() throws JMSException;
```

In other words, it is for use cases where you absolutely don't want to block the thread for any time at all, if there is not currently a message that has already been sent to the consumer by the broker - not even waiting for a network I/O to complete, which is exactly how ActiveMQ has implemented it - initiates an I/O but returns null if that I/O doesn't complete immediately (which is most likely the case if there's a network involved).