# Spring Integration Bridge with poller not working as expected for JMS

Tags: spring-integration

Using spring-integration 5.0.7 to throttle the bridging of msgs between two JMS queues.

The docs at: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.7.RELEASE/reference/html/messaging-channels-section.html#bridge-namespace

suggest:

```
<int:bridge input-channel="pollable" output-channel="subscribable">
     <int:poller max-messages-per-poll="10" fixed-rate="5000"/>
 </int:bridge>
```

But schema validator complains "no nested poller allowed for subscribable input channel" on bridge elt.

But, if I put the poller on the input-channel-adapter as in:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
             xmlns:int-jms="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jms"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jms
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jms/spring-integration-jms.xsd
 ">
    <int:channel id="inChannel" />
    <int:channel id="outChannel" />

    <int-jms:inbound-channel-adapter id="jmsIn" connection-factory="jmsConnectionFactory" destination-name="_dev.inQueue" channel="inChannel">
       <int:poller fixed-delay="5000" max-messages-per-poll="2"/>
    </int-jms:inbound-channel-adapter>

    <int-jms:outbound-channel-adapter id="jmsOut" connection-factory="jmsConnectionFactory" destination-name="_dev.outQueue" channel="outChannel"/>
    <int:bridge input-channel="inChannel" output-channel="outChannel">
    </int:bridge>
</beans:beans>
```

Nothing is ever moved from input to output.

How can I bridge from one JMS queue to another with a rate-limit?

Update:

Turning on logging confirms nothing getting picked up from input channel but otherwise not helpful:

```
018-08-10 15:36:33.345 DEBUG 112066 --- [ask-scheduler-1] o.s.i.e.SourcePollingChannelAdapter      : Received no Message during the poll, returning 'false'
2018-08-10 15:36:38.113 DEBUG 112066 --- [ask-scheduler-2] o.s.integration.jms.DynamicJmsTemplate   : Executing callback on JMS Session: ActiveMQSession {id=ID:whitechapel-35247-1533940593148-3:2:1,started=true} java.lang.Object@5c278302
2018-08-10 15:36:38.116 DEBUG 112066 --- [ask-scheduler-2] o.s.i.e.SourcePollingChannelAdapter      : Received no Message during the poll, returning 'false'
2018-08-10 15:36:43.115 DEBUG 112066 --- [ask-scheduler-1] o.s.integration.jms.DynamicJmsTemplate   : Executing callback on JMS Session: ActiveMQSession {id=ID:whitechapel-35247-1533940593148-3:3:1,started=true} java.lang.Object@1c09a81e
2018-08-10 15:36:43.118 DEBUG 112066 --- [ask-scheduler-1] o.s.i.e.SourcePollingChannelAdapter      : Received no Message during the poll, returning 'false'
```

Comment: You don't need a bridge, you can just use one channel. That said, it should work OK. Turn on DEBUG logging to see if it gives you any clues.

Comment: I guess if I wanted to handle the msg in spring-integration, yes, I wouldnt need to bridge to another queue...but for now I want to keep the current consumer.

Comment: In the code above, you are simply bridging in the inbound adapter's channel to the outbound adapter's channel. It's unnecessary; both adapters can use the same channel; the inbound adapter's poller will send the message directly to the outbound adapter.

Comment: Ok, tried using one channel. Made no difference. Are we sure that polling is supported on inbound-channel-adapter using a JmsConnectionFactory?  If I use a straight message-driven-channel-adapter it works fine, but of course no throttling.

Comment: I said it wouldn't make a difference; the bridge is just not needed. As I also said, DEBUG logging will show you messaging activity.

Comment: I believe I put the logging of org.springframework.integration in the edited question above. Or is there some other pkg to look at?

Comment: Those logs mean the queue has no records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a Spring Boot app, using Java DSL configuration which is the exact equivalent of what you have in XML (minus the bridge); it works fine.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class So51792909Application {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(So51792909Application.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So51792909Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(JmsTemplate template) {
        return args -> {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                template.convertAndSend("foo", "test");
            }
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow flow(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(Jms.inboundAdapter(connectionFactory)
                        .destination("foo"), e -> e
                            .poller(Pollers
                                    .fixedDelay(5000)
                                    .maxMessagesPerPoll(2)))
                .handle(Jms.outboundAdapter(connectionFactory)
                        .destination("bar"))
                .get();
    }

    @JmsListener(destination = "bar")
    public void listen(String in) {
        logger.info(in);
    }

}
```

and

```
2018-08-10 19:38:52.534  INFO 13408 --- [enerContainer-1] com.example.So51792909Application        : test
2018-08-10 19:38:52.543  INFO 13408 --- [enerContainer-1] com.example.So51792909Application        : test
2018-08-10 19:38:57.566  INFO 13408 --- [enerContainer-1] com.example.So51792909Application        : test
2018-08-10 19:38:57.582  INFO 13408 --- [enerContainer-1] com.example.So51792909Application        : test
2018-08-10 19:39:02.608  INFO 13408 --- [enerContainer-1] com.example.So51792909Application        : test
2018-08-10 19:39:02.622  INFO 13408 --- [enerContainer-1] com.example.So51792909Application        : test
2018-08-10 19:39:07.640  INFO 13408 --- [enerContainer-1] com.example.So51792909Application        : test
2018-08-10 19:39:07.653  INFO 13408 --- [enerContainer-1] com.example.So51792909Application        : test
2018-08-10 19:39:12.672  INFO 13408 --- [enerContainer-1] com.example.So51792909Application        : test
2018-08-10 19:39:12.687  INFO 13408 --- [enerContainer-1] com.example.So51792909Application        : test
```

As you can see, the consumer gets 2 messages every 5 seconds.

Your debug log implies there are no messages in the queue.

**EDIT**

I figured it out; the XML parser sets the JmsTemplate receiveTimeout to nowait (-1). Since you are not using a caching connection factory, we'll never get a message because the ActiveMQ client returns immediately if there's not already a message present in the client ([see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50953877/jmstemplate-with-receive-timeout-no-wait-doesnt-retrieve-messages-from-jms-queu/50968706#50968706)). Since there's no caching going on, we get a new consumer on every poll (and do a no-wait receive each time).

The DSL leaves the JmsTemplate's default (Infinite wait - which is actually wrong since it blocks the poller thread indefinitely if there are no messages).

To fix the XML version, adding `receive-timeout="1000"` fixes it.

However, it's better to use a `CachingConnectionFactory` to avoid creating a new connection/session/consumer on each poll.

Unfortunately, configurating a `CachingConnectionFactory` turns off Spring Boot's auto-configuration. This is [fixed in Boot 2.1](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/12161).

I have opened an issue to resolve the inconsistency between the DSL and XML [here](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-4519).

If you stick with the DSL, I would recommend setting the receive timeout to something reasonable, rather than indefinite:

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow flow(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(Jms.inboundAdapter(connectionFactory)
                    .configureJmsTemplate(t -> t.receiveTimeout(1000))
                    .destination("foo"), e -> e
                        .poller(Pollers
                                .fixedDelay(5000)
                                .maxMessagesPerPoll(2)))
            .handle(Jms.outboundAdapter(connectionFactory)
                    .destination("bar"))
            .get();
}
```

But, the best solution is to use a `CachingConnectionFactory`.

Comment: Are you testing with an embedded ActiveMQ broker? If so, you probably need to use a `CachingConnectionFactory` to avoid the broker stopping/starting between sneding the test messages and the polls, which could cause the queue to go away. In my example, the connection is kept open by the listener.

Comment: No, it is a standalone broker and AMQ console insists there are things on queue. If I change the xml flow from inbound-channel-adapter to  message-driven-channel-adapter (without poller) it receives them just fine.  Meanwhile, the Java DSL example works perfectly, so will be using that approach.